# Failed to start Telnet Server: "Unit telnet.service not found"

Tags: ubuntu, telnet

I am doing a research on Telnet communication and I need to test its communication although it is not secure.

I have an Ubuntu machine 18.04 on my EC2 (**I opened inbound port 23 for everyone in AWS**).
I checked the status of the Telnet an it wasn't found:

```
root@ip:~# service telnet status
Unit telnet.service could not be found.
```

I tried to install it with the following commands

```
apt update
apt --fix-broken install
apt-get install xinetd telnetd
```

After that I created the file `/etc/xinetd.d/telnet` with the information I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/448930/780516):

```
service telnet
{
disable = no
flags = REUSE
socket_type = stream
wait = no
user = root
server = /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
log_on_failure += USERID
}
```

I tried to restart the service but it failed:

```
root@ip:~# service xinetd restart  
root@ip:~# service telnet restart  
Failed to restart telnet.service: Unit telnet.service not found.
```

Any idea how to continue from here?

I checked the status of `xinetd` and it seems that the problem is that it uses the port 23 of telnet:

```
root@ip:~# service xinetd status
● xinetd.service - LSB: Starts or stops the xinetd daemon.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/xinetd; generated)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-02-18 16:25:05 UTC; 4min 7s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 16422 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/xinetd stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16492 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/xinetd reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16428 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/xinetd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 1140)
   CGroup: /system.slice/xinetd.service
           └─16455 /usr/sbin/xinetd -pidfile /run/xinetd.pid -stayalive -inetd_compat -inetd_ipv6

Feb 18 16:27:18 ip-172-31-17-160 xinetd[16455]: bind retry attempt 8
Feb 18 16:27:18 ip-172-31-17-160 xinetd[16455]: bind failed (Address already in use (errno = 98)). service = telnet
Feb 18 16:27:18 ip-172-31-17-160 xinetd[16455]: bind retry attempt 9
Feb 18 16:27:18 ip-172-31-17-160 xinetd[16455]: bind failed (Address already in use (errno = 98)). service = telnet
Feb 18 16:27:18 ip-172-31-17-160 xinetd[16455]: bind retry attempt 10
Feb 18 16:27:18 ip-172-31-17-160 xinetd[16455]: bind failed (Address already in use (errno = 98)). service = telnet
Feb 18 16:27:18 ip-172-31-17-160 xinetd[16455]: Service telnet failed to start and is deactivated.
Feb 18 16:27:18 ip-172-31-17-160 xinetd[16455]: Reconfigured: new=0 old=1 dropped=0 (services)
Feb 18 16:27:18 ip-172-31-17-160 xinetd[16492]:    ...done.
Feb 18 16:27:18 ip-172-31-17-160 systemd[1]: Reloaded LSB: Starts or stops the xinetd daemon..
```

I changed the telnet port from `/etc/services` to `2345` and restart the `xinetd` service but it still show me (`xinet -d`) the same errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ubuntu 18.04**

Install the packages

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt install xinetd telnetd telnet -y
```

Create a new file `/etc/xinetd.d/telnet` with following entries:

```
service telnet
{
disable = no
flags = REUSE
socket_type = stream
wait = no
user = root
server = /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
log_on_failure += USERID
}
```

Then restart xinetd service

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/xinetd restart
```

Time to test from server side:

```
$ telnet localhost
```

**CentOS-7**

Install the packages

```
$ sudo yum clean all && yum repolist
$ sudo yum install xinetd telnet-server telnet -y
```

Enable and start the services

```
$ sudo systemctl enable telnet.socket
$ sudo systemctl start telnet.socket
```

Allow telnet (TCP/23) through the firewall

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=23/tcp
$ sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Test from server side

```
$ telnet localhost
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't find `telnet-server`: `Package 'telnet-server' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Did you refresh the apt packages by running apt-get update?

Comment: yes, it still doesn't find it. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Let me double check. The command work for me on Debain Linux

Comment: My bad. The command I shared was tested on CentOS-7

Comment: I go it working in Ubuntu-18.04. I will update the answer

Comment: I did those steps already and it didn't work, I tried again following your instructions and now it worked. So I don't know what was the problem exactly but thanks for checking and providing all these helpful details, including CentOs. Now I was able to connect from external computer to my AWS using Telent. For those who read it, also make sure that port 23 is opened for inbound connection in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `xinetd`, it's not needed anymore. I'd suggest removing `telnetd` also and then install only `telnetd`. By default uses `openbsd-inetd` nowadays.

But do you really need telnetd? It's insecure and should not be used, sshd is more than enough.

Comment: This is for research purposes, I first need to check the most unsecure and basic connection, so it's okay for me.

Comment: I removed both `xinetd` and `telnetd` and re-installed `telnetd` but I still don't have a way to connect. I also didn't see any port 23 listening using `netstat -ntlp`.

Comment: Was `openbsd-inetd` and `tcpd` installed as dependencies? In that case you can `man inetd.conf`, where you can find examples. Probably adding `telnet stream tcp nowait root /usr/sbin/tcpd in.telnetd` in `/etc/inetd.conf` is enough, but have a look.